# $g$ is Lebesgue Integrable Implies $g < \infty$ a.e. (Papa Rudin 1.41)

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-integral

In the last sentence of the proof of 1.41, Rudin RCA, he says that if $g \in L^1(\mu)$ then $g < \infty$ a.e. (in this case $g$ is a function into $[0, \infty]$). I understand how this works intuitively, the sets at which $g$ is equal to $\infty$ are not contributing to the integral and thus the integral remains finite.  But I'm having trouble showing this.

Comment: Suppose not. Then the integral of $g$ over some set of positive measure is infinite, contradicting the membership of $g$ in $L^1$.

Comment: @Bachmaninoff   How would you show that the integral is infinite.  Could we use the definition of lebesgue integral?  That is defined with simple functions tho, so there would be no subset of $X$ where $s = \infty$ because $s$ is finite.

Comment: If $g$ is infinite on some measurable set $A$, then $g \ge n \cdot 1_A$ for all $n$ hence $\int |g| \ge n \mu A$ for all $n$. If $g$ is integrable then you must have $\mu A = 0$.

Comment: @copper.hat  When we negate the statement, for contradiction, can we assume that the set at which $g = \infty$ is measurable?  I got up to that point but I had trouble with the measurability of $A$.

Comment: Of course. If $g$ is measurable then $g^{-1}(\{\infty\})$ is measurable.

Comment: What statement are you negating?

Comment: @copper.hat   wait is it?   is the set $\{ \infty  \}$ an open set in $[0, \infty]$ ?

Comment: If $g$ is integrable it is measurable. I don't know where you are getting an open set from. You are given that $g$ is measurable, so if you want to prove the contra positive you need to show that if a measurable $g$ is infinite on a set of positive measure then it is not in $L^1$.

Comment: disregard that last post let me clean it up

Comment: The definition of measurable function is $f^{-1} (V)$  is measurable for any open $V$. Thus if $g$ were meas. then if $\{ \infty \} $ were open, $g^{-1} (\{  \infty  \})$ would be meas. and we're done.

Comment: Ok ok let me start form the beginning:     I'm negating the statement ($g(x) < \infty$ a.e. on $X$) which is equivalent to (The set $N = \{  x \in X : g(x) = \infty  \} $ is measurable and $ \mu(N) = 0$).   The negation would be that ($\mu(N) \neq 0$ or N is not measurable) .   Is this correct?

Comment: You need to revisit the measurable bit. If $f$ is measurable then the inverse image of any Borel set (which includes points) is measurable.

Comment: Well, you can word it however you like, but I think it is easier to show that if a measurable $g$ is infinite on a set of positive measure then $g$ is not integrable.

Comment: Then it follows that if $g$ is integrable (and hence measurable) it cannot be infinite on a set of positive measure.

Comment: I understand that part.  I'm going to have to think about it for a while... thanks for the help!